# SVN error on commit: "svnlook: Path 'path/to/dir' is not a file"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, simplesamlphp, svnlook

Whenever I'm trying to commit the changes through TortoiseSVN, I get below errors,

```
svnlook: Path 'path/to/dir' is not a file
```

I tried below solutions,

- Clean repo by Settings > Saved data
- New checkout

This is happening only for specific directory and it's contents, rest files are fine. 
The directory is, https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp

Update: 
We are using SVN for versioning and we integrated above simplesamlphp library into our code. Now we are trying to commit into SVN while committing I'm getting above error

Answer (score 0):

@Amit, You can't use TortoiseSVN for GIT repositories. For GIT repositories, use

- https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis
- https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean I cannot commit GIT files to SVN? But my project requires SVN and I'm using simplesamlphp library as a third-party library.

Comment: @AmitSukapure. Can you please provide more information as sample, i.e., Working copy path, GIT repo path, folder that you are committing, etc.?

Comment: Hi, sorry I actually working for an organization and they have their own SVN setup. So couldn't provide that.
The folder I'm committing is, https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp

Comment: @AmitSukapure We're all confused because GitHub (as the name suggests) is a well-known code hosting service that uses **git**, not Subversion. Sure, it has a svn to git bridge that allows some (limited) functionality but you just don't contribute with Subversion to projects that use git.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks! Just to be clearer, we are using SVN in our organization for versioning and as our product required the github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp library. Now I've integrated this library and need to commit my code along with this library. 
I deleted .git files from this library.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you don't have anything unintended in the [Hook Scripts](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) section of your TortoiseSVN settings. However, I suspect that whoever manages the repository has installed a [server-side hook](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-hooks.html) that is broken. If that's the case, there's probably nothing you can do about that, apart from warning the repo owners.